# AX 2009 to AX 2012 upgrade of VAR layer

Tags: upgrade, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009

We are trying to Upgrade from Ax 2009 to Ax 2012. In ax 2009, we have developments on Var layer.

Can someone please explain all the scenario I need to do, from beginning to end, in a short variant?

Answer (score 1):

To do code upgrade you can follow below steps.

1. Create two project in Ax 2009, one with the objects of lower layers you have customized and another with newly created objects.
2. Create a model in Ax 2012 in var layer and import your project XPO's. Compare and take the lower layer object modification.
3. Another thing to note is if your customization already available in Ax 2012, remove from your Var layer code and there are many framework changes in Ax 2012 which may need re-writing of the customization. Developer need to analyse and rewrite and if needed may need to redesign.

The upgrade process involves, analyse the new functional and technical changes, do GAP fitting/mapping if needed and plan for code upgrade and data upgrade. Please refer MS documents for sure steps/checklist and best practices for upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. This is something that a development/upgrade expert would decide what to do.

Are you the end customer doing the upgrade internally?  Do you have the layer access keys to get into the VAR layer?

Typically you'd migrate your VAR changes to the VAR layer of your AX12 environment.  If you're a customer doing the upgrade internally and don't have access to the VAR layer, you may be able to get the VAR keys from your VAR or Microsoft or you can just migrate to the CUS layer, but you'll possibly face some ID conflict issues during the migration...but I'm not sure on that.  I'd have to dig into the upgrade framework to figure out how it identifies target tables.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply, i am Administrator, Developer of Axapta systems in this company, but i never did a upgrade before, so i m not sure of Full Life Cycle of Upgrade process. I have access and keys to all of layer. 
Sincerely.

Comment: It is not an easy task.  It took our company almost a year to complete an upgrade.  If you have light customization it will still take you months.

Answer (score 0):

There is no next, next, next description of an AX 2012 upgrade, because no such description can exist due to the complexities involved.

You will have to read [the official documentaion on the subject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362002.aspx).
There is also [an upgrade resource page](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axresources/archive/2014/02/10/resource-page-for-upgrading-to-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012) available.

Happy reading.